# React.js - Value of checkbox not reflecting initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, components

I'm rendering checkboxes with the following code:

```
export default class Day extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            startTime: this.props.startTime,
            endTime: this.props.endTime,
            available: this.props.available
        }
        console.log(this.state.available)
    }

    return (
        <div className='day'>
            <label className='name'>
                {day.name}
                <input
                    type='checkbox'
                    checked={this.state.available}
                    onChange={this.handleAvailableChange}
                    />
            </label>
            {this.state.available}

        </div>
    );
}
```

This `Day` component is rendered from a parent component like so:

```
export default class Schedule extends React.Component {

    render () {
        const dayComponents = this.props.days.map( (day) =>
            <Day key={day.id}
                startTime={this.state[day.name].start}
                endTime={this.state[day.name].end}
                available={this.state[day.name].available}
                day={day}
                handleDayChange={(day, startOrEnd, time, available) => this.handleDayChange(day, startOrEnd, time, available) }
            />

        return (
            <div>
                {dayComponents}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

... where `this.props.days` is an array of day objects that look like so:

```
#<Day id: 14, name: "Saturday">
```

And a state that looks like so:

```
{"Sunday": {"start": 0, "end": 0, "available": true},
"Monday": {"start": 0, "end": 0, "available": true},
etc...}
```

The value of my checkbox should be initialized based on the value of `this.state.available`, but every checkbox is checked when the component is rendered.

I'm looking at the value of `this.state.available` in two different places, and in both places, I get 5 trues and 2 falses.

Is there some aspect of the component life cycle that I'm missing here? Do I need to utilize something like `getInitialState()` (didn't change anything when I tried)?

Hoping this is something simple and stupid I overlooked since it seems like such basic functionality...

***Edit:***

I've removed state from the `Day` component and rendering the checkboxes as follows:

```
<label className='name'>
    {day.name}
    <input
        type='checkbox'
        checked={this.props.available}
        onChange={this.handleAvailableChange}
        />
</label>
{this.props.available}
```

However, this is still the output I get:

[image: Screen cap]

It is also worth noting that if I assign a static `false` to the value of `checked`, an unchecked checkbox is returned.

***Edit 2 (Solution):***

Turns out that when I was saving the schedule to my database (which is where I pull the `available` values from), I was saving the booleans to strings because the parameters in the AJAX request were getting automatically cast to a different data type.

So I was trying to set the value of `checked` to `"false"`, which always returns true since it's an existent string.

Comment: Not clear, you are rendering only one check box where are other check boxes, this.state.available is an array of true and false correct ?

Comment: I think the code for component which wraps your checkbox component should be included.

Comment: Apologies. I forget sometimes that what I assume is obvious may be confusing without the proper context. I've updated my question to provide the call to the component from its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are managing the `state` by the parent component, i will suggest you to not store the values again in child component, directly use `this.props.keyName`. You are passing a change `function` also, use that method to update the parent `state` value, once you update the parent `state`, updated values will get passed to child component automatically. On `re-render` it will reflect all the changes in ui also.

Check this working snippet:

```js
let days = [
    {name:"Sunday"}, 
    {name:"Monday"},
    {name:"Tuesday"},
    {name:"Wednesday"},
    {name:"Thursday"},
    {name:"Friday"},
    {name:"Saturday"},
];

class Schedule extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            "Sunday": {"start": 0, "end": 0, "available": true},
            "Monday": {"start": 0, "end": 0, "available": true},
            "Tuesday": {"start": 0, "end": 0, "available": true},
            "Wednesday": {"start": 0, "end": 0, "available": true},
            "Thursday": {"start": 0, "end": 0, "available": true},
            "Friday": {"start": 0, "end": 0, "available": false},
            "Saturday": {"start": 0, "end": 0, "available": false},
        }
    }
    
    handleDayChange(value, dayName){
       let obj = {...this.state[dayName]};
       obj.available = value;
       this.setState({[dayName]: obj});
    }

    render () {
        const dayComponents = this.props.days.map(day =>
            <Day 
                key={day.name}
                startTime={this.state[day.name].start}
                endTime={this.state[day.name].end}
                available={this.state[day.name].available}
                name={day.name}
                handleDayChange={(value, dayName) => this.handleDayChange(value, dayName) }
            />
        )
        return (
            <div>
                {dayComponents}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Day extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        }
        this.handleAvailableChange = this.handleAvailableChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleAvailableChange(e){
        this.props.handleDayChange(e.target.checked, this.props.name);
    }

    render(){
        let values = this.props;
        return (
            <div className='day'>
                <label className='name'>
                    {values.name}
                    <input
                        type='checkbox'
                        checked={values.available}
                        onChange={this.handleAvailableChange}
                    />
                </label>
                {values.available + ""}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Schedule days={days}/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: I removed the state form my `Day` component and changed the value of checked to pull `this.props.available` instead of `this.state.available`. However, all checkboxes are still initializing with a checked value of true. However, literally right after the checkbox, I'm outputting the value of `this.props.available`, and those outputs return the correct values I expect... I'm updating the question to show this.